why useEffect clear function runs on strict mode before closing the component?
I have to make an editable and addable form. So the initial value will be used for adding and updating the form using the initial value. I need to know which value will be added and which one will be edit. So, I decided to choose id inside the initial value ( only the edit value has id ).
I am trying to use the state and clear the state after closing the component. But in strict mode, It clears the state before closing the component.
import { FunctionComponent, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  FormProvider,
  SubmitHandler,
  useForm,
  UseFormReturn,
} from "react-hook-form";
import { IDivisionMaster } from "./IDivisionMaster";
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import TextInputFieldC from "../../Components/TextInput/TextInputFieldC";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../Redux/Store/Hooks";
import { addDivisionMaster } from "../../Redux/Slices/DivisionMaster/AddDivisionMasterSlice";

interface DivisionMasterFormProps {
  formRef: React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement>;
  initialValues: IDivisionMaster;
  setInitialValues: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IDivisionMaster>>;
}

const DivisionMasterForm: FunctionComponent<DivisionMasterFormProps> = (
  props
) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const divisionSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string({ message: "Please enter Name" }),
    code: z.string({ message: "Please enter Code" }),
  });
  const methods = useForm<IDivisionMaster>({
    defaultValues: props.initialValues,
    resolver: zodResolver(divisionSchema),
  });
  console.log(props.initialValues.id);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IDivisionMaster> = (val) => {
    if (props.initialValues.id) {
      console.log("update");
    } else {
      dispatch(addDivisionMaster(val));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      props.setInitialValues({});
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form
        ref={props.formRef}
        onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="form_content"
      >
        <TextInputFieldC name="name" label="Name" />
        <TextInputFieldC name="code" label="Code" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

export default DivisionMasterForm;

The useState was send by parent component.
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState<IDivisionMaster>({});
  
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

It always returns {}.
I need to know why, and the solution to this situation.

This question is similar to: React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is an expected behaviour

I need a solution to this situation.

Do you really need to pass the setInitialValue to the child?
If yes, I think it will be easier to put the setter inside the form's onFinish method (if it is associated with the destruction of your component).
In your case here as the strictMode is enable in dev mode, all component will be destroyed and remounted on the init of them. It is an expected behavior to spot all the non pure component (which most of the time create weird bug).

I need to clear the form initial value when close the form component.

Well you can use the key props on your component <FormComponent initialValues={initialValues} key={initialValues} />. It will reset each time the initialValues change. You actually dont need to put the initialValues inside a useState

Is this using the key props correct method?
I used only the map function for uniqueness.

Yes key is like an id, and when the id change, React understand that this is a totaly new component and reset everything. See the documentation : using key

I got it. Thank you.
